# The limit of arccos(x) is the arccos(x) of the limit?

Tags: limits, trigonometry, continuity

Recently I came across a proof using the apparant fact that $$\lim_{x \rightarrow a} \cos^{-1}(x)=\cos^{-1}(\lim_{x \rightarrow a} x)$$ with justification: *because arccos(x) is a continuous function*.

Is this limit property true for all continuous functions or a class of continuous functions and can it be proved easily? If the property is true, I am not looking for a formal proof rather a general outline or conceptual proof.

This seems to make intuitive sense, but I cannot think of any type of specific reason for why this property may be true.

Comment: It is true just as long as both limits exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined as [continuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function) at $a \in \mathbb{R}$ if $$\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)=f(a)$$ or equivalently if $$\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)=f(\lim_{x \rightarrow a} x).$$  It is continuous if it is continuous at $a$ for all $a$ in its domain.

For $\arccos$, we have the restricted domain $[-1,1]$.  So, if $a \in [-1,1]$, then $$\lim_{x \rightarrow a} \arccos(x)=\arccos(\lim_{x \rightarrow a} x)$$ is equivalent to saying $\arccos$ is continuous at $a$.